# How to deserialize fields from subobjects using readComponent()

Tags: delphi

I am using writeComponent() to serialize an object and a subobject. This appears to work without any problems. In the following example I serialize an object of TConfigData and a subobject of TFoo:

```
object TConfigData
  myInteger = 999
  object TFoo
    value = 777
  end
end
```

However when I try to read it back in, readCompontent only recovers the value myInteger in the root object, it fails to recover the value in the subobject TFoo which it sets to zero. I enclose the entire code below. The two main classes are TConfigData and within that TFoo. I've done extensive searching of the internet but I can't understand why it is failing to read TFoo.value.

Any suggestions for how to get the reading to work? (Using XE6). I am sure there is a simple explanation but it evades me for the moment.

```
unit ufMain;

interface

uses Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,    
System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, V     
Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TFoo = class (TComponent)
   private
     fValue : integer;
   published
     property value : integer read fValue write fValue;
  end;

  TConfigData = class (TComponent)
     private
       fInteger : integer;
       fFoo : TFoo;  // <- Subobject
       function ComponentToStringProc(Component: TComponent): string;
       class function StringToComponentProc(Value: string): TComponent;
     protected
       procedure GetChildren(Proc: TGetChildProc; Root: TComponent); override;
      function   GetChildOwner: TComponent; override;
      published
       property myInteger : Integer read fInteger write fInteger;
       property foo : TFoo read fFoo write fFoo;
     public
       procedure save (fileName : string);
       class function  load (fileName : string) : TConfigData;
       function  getConfigStreamString : string;
       constructor Create (AOwner : TComponent); override;
       destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

Uses IOUTils;

procedure TConfigData.GetChildren(Proc: TGetChildProc; Root: TComponent);
var i : Integer;
begin
  inherited GetChildren(Proc, Root);
  for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
    Proc(Components[i]);
end;

function TConfigData.GetChildOwner: TComponent;
begin
  result := Self;
end;

constructor TConfigData.Create (AOwner : TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  fFoo := TFoo.Create (self);
  // foo.SetSubComponent (True); <- I don't want to use this because it flattens the dfm file.
end;

destructor TConfigData.Destroy;
begin
  fFoo.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TConfigData.getConfigStreamString : string;
begin
   result := ComponentToStringProc (self);
end;

procedure TConfigData.save (fileName : string);
var configStr : string;
begin
  configStr := ComponentToStringProc (self);
  TFile.WriteAllText (fileName, configStr);
end;

class function TConfigData.load (fileName : string) : TConfigData;
var configStr : string;
begin
  configStr := TFile.ReadAllText (fileName);
  result := StringToComponentProc (configStr) as TConfigData;
end;

function TConfigData.ComponentToStringProc(Component: TComponent): string;
var
  BinStream:TMemoryStream;
  StrStream: TStringStream;
  s: string;
begin
  BinStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    StrStream := TStringStream.Create(s);
    try
      BinStream.WriteComponent(Component);
      BinStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      ObjectBinaryToText(BinStream, StrStream);
      StrStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      Result:= StrStream.DataString;
    finally
      StrStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    BinStream.Free
  end;
end;

class function TConfigData.StringToComponentProc(Value: string): TComponent;
var
  StrStream:TStringStream;
  BinStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  StrStream := TStringStream.Create(Value);
  try
    BinStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      ObjectTextToBinary(StrStream, BinStream);
      BinStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      Result:= BinStream.ReadComponent(nil);
    finally
      BinStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    StrStream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var config : TConfigData;
    configStr : string;
begin
  config := TConfigData.Create (nil);
  config.myInteger := 999;
  config.foo.value := 777;
  config.save('c:\\tmp\\config.dat');
  Memo1.text := config.getConfigStreamString;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var config : TConfigData;
begin
  config := TConfigData.load ('c:\\tmp\\config.dat');
  Memo1.Clear;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(inttostr (config.myInteger));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(inttostr(config.foo.value));
end;

initialization
 RegisterClasses([TConfigData, TFoo]);
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different ways to deal with subobjects.

One of them is `SetSubComponent(true)`, or using `TPersistent` instead of `TComponent` in the first place. In this case, it is responsibility of `TConfigData` to create subobject in its constructor and destroy it in destructor. Streaming system "expects" that component already exists and it only needs to modify its fields.

But child components are treated in different way. They are created by streaming system itself and belong to that component which was returned by `GetChildOwner` (in your case it is `TConfigData`). If child component doesn't have a name (or say, has empty name), no more actions are performed. But in case, it has a name, streaming system looks for published fields of the same name to assign them to newly created component. It's how it works in VCL: `TForm1` (for example) has all the controls as published fields and these fields point to controls which were loaded from .dfm automatically.

In your case component `TFoo` is successfully loaded and it is listed in Components[], but it has nothing to do with `foo` property which leads to empty component which was created in `TConfigData` constructor.

**How to fix it**

Child components have weaker connection with its parent than subcomponents, it was expected that parent has no idea how many children it can have, which is appropriate for most controls. That's why creating children inside constructor wasn't expected. If it is known from beginning what children of what types are needed, using subcomponents seems more logical.

Nevertheless, it can be done with child components, too.

Instead of property Foo, use published field Foo:

```
TConfigData = class (TComponent)
     private
       fInteger : integer;
       function ComponentToStringProc(Component: TComponent): string;
       class function StringToComponentProc(Value: string): TComponent;
     protected
       procedure GetChildren(Proc: TGetChildProc; Root: TComponent); override;
      function   GetChildOwner: TComponent; override;
      published
       Foo: TFoo;
       property myInteger : Integer read fInteger write fInteger;
     public
       procedure save (fileName : string);
       class function  load (fileName : string) : TConfigData;
       function  getConfigStreamString : string;
       constructor Create (AOwner : TComponent); override;
       destructor Destroy; override;
  end;
```

In constructor, we create new TFoo and give it a name:

```
constructor TConfigData.Create (AOwner : TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Foo := TFoo.Create (self);
  Foo.name = 'Foo'; //looks like tautology but it's not!
end;
```

But when loading from file, we destroy all existing components, because streaming system creates them from scratch, name conflict would occur otherwise. Something like that:

```
class function TConfigData.StringToComponentProc(Value: string): TComponent;
var
  StrStream:TStringStream;
  BinStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  StrStream := TStringStream.Create(Value);
  try
    BinStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      ObjectTextToBinary(StrStream, BinStream);
      BinStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      Result:= TConfigFile.Create(nil); //it creates components we don't need
      Result.DestroyComponents; //not any more
      BinStream.ReadComponent(Result); //it reads to component already created
    finally
      BinStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    StrStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Now it should work.

Maybe it's more elegant to remove constructor `Create(aOwner: TComponent)` at all (inherited would suffice) and use another one, like `CreateNew` which is called only from you code, in case this config file wasn't found. Or, instead of constructor use procedure `InitializeDefault` or smth like this, which would set all fields to default values and create `TFoo` if needed.

It's even possible to never create `TFoo` explicitly at runtime, but rather to load `TConfigData` either from file, or from resource where it has its default values stored.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What you gave does work. In my particular application I won't have subsubobjects but if one had multiple layers of objects I wonder how it would work.

Comment: @rhody It would work just fine. To implement it I'd introduce abstract class TStreamingClass with methods GetChildren and GetChildOwner implemented as in your TConfigData, so TConfigInfo and TFoo and other components could be all descendants from TStreamingClass. And then you can make hierarchical structures as complex as needed, very much like it's done in dfm describing forms, though there is little difference. In visual controls form is owner of all the components, while in TConfigData owner is the same as parent.

Comment: @rhody That's why in form, if you has Panel1 on which sits Button1, you write form1.button1 or simply button1, without mentioning Panel1 at all. In your code, if ConfigData has sub-object Foo which has sub-object Bar, you'll have to write ConfigData.Foo.Bar. I think, it's fine, there is no need for 2 different hierarchies as parent/child and owner/its components, it would be over-complication.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to get the reading work, I can only explain what's wrong with the code.

Replace the Button2 handler by

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var config : TConfigData;
  I: Integer;

begin
  config := TConfigData.load ('c:\temp\config.dat');
  Memo1.Clear;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(inttostr (config.myInteger));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(inttostr(config.ComponentCount));
  for I:= 0 to config.ComponentCount - 1 do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(inttostr((config.Components[I] as TFoo).value));
end;
```

Now it is getting clear what is going on under the hood. The `TConfigData` instance you loaded from stream contains 2 instances of `TFoo` - the first one is created in `TConfigData` constructor, the second one is created by Delphi streaming system, and the second one is loaded by the '777' value.